# Power BI - Gerar tabela com DAX filtrando linhas

Tags: tabela-html, dax

Olá, preciso criar uma tabela usando DAX que filtre as linhas duplicadas pegando somente uma, aquela que contenha o maior valor da coluna [Valor]. Exemplo:

Quando utilizo o código:

```
Tabela = 

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
   'Cliente'[Cod_cliente],
   'Cliente'[Valor],
    FILTER(
        'Cliente', 
        NOT '[Cod_cliente] == BLANK() 
      // Como devo calcular esse filtro de duplicatas???
    )
)
```

Ele gera uma tabela assim:

| Cod_cliente | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 22 |
| 02 | 12 |
| 01 | 23 |
| 02 | 14 |
| 02 | 30 |
| 04 | 10 |
| 03 | 12 |
| 04 | 6 |

Gostaria que ele gerasse a tabela contendo somente um valor por código do cliente e que esse valor fosse o maior. A tabela que desejo retornar:

| Cod_cliente | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 23 |
| 02 | 30 |
| 03 | 12 |
| 04 | 10 |

Esse é só um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer, a tabela real na qual estou trabalhando retorna milhares de linhas. Estou completamente perdido.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o maior valor de uma coluna você pode utilizar a função MAX. O seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

Tabela =

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
   Cliente[Cod_cliente],
   "Valor", MAX(Cliente[Valor]),
    FILTER(
        Cliente, 
        NOT [Cod_cliente] == BLANK() 
    )
)
```